# How do I make intel TBB libraries available on Xeon Phi

Tags: c++, tbb, xeon-phi

I am trying to use Intel TBB in a segment of Xeon Phi offload code. The code fails to compile with error `error : *MIC* cannot open source file "tbb\parallel_for.h"`

I have the MPSS stack installed, I ran the `binutils.msi` utility, and my includes at the top of the offloaded code file is as follows:

```
#include <offload.h>
#pragma offload_attribute(push, target(mic))
#include <tbb\parallel_for.h>
#pragma offload_attribute(pop)
//other includes and code follows
```

Why does this fail?

What do I need to change to offload and run my code sucessfully?

**EDIT :**

After adding the `-tbb` option to the "Additional Options for MIC Offload Compiler" the compiler has found the `<tbb\parallel_for.h>` file however it gives several warnings and errors about tbb library code not being marked shared. follows is my offloaded code segment.

```
#pragma offload target(mic:0) in(nums) out(results)
tbb::parallel_for<int>(0,ARRAY_SIZE,1,[&](int i)
{
    results[i] = findZero(nums[i]);
});
```

Comment: Did you add the location of the headers to you include path?

Comment: @Captain Obvilous I believe what you are talking about is done when the `binutils.msi` utility is run, although I am not positive. If not, how might I attempt to do that for the Xeon Phi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offload compiler basically consists of two (very) different compilers called separately on the same code. Each of them generally has its own command line, include, and library paths; and not all the command line options translated from host to the MIC compiler. In case of TBB, compiler has special option `/Qtbb` or just `-tbb` which takes care of all the paths for both compilers.

Please refer to `tbb\examples\GettingStarted\SUB_STRING_FINDER\sub_string_finder_extended.cpp` for how to use TBB from offload region. And check out the `Makefile` for how to build the example.

In order to run the code from MSVC environment, you need to setup the same environment as for Intel Compiler used to build the GettingStarted\Sub_string_finder example. The easy way to duplicate the environment inside MSVC is to run it from the same console window where the example works:

> [devenv /useenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241275.aspx)

Or specifically, you need to set the `MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to point to MIC TBB binaries as shown [here for other libraries](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/window-phi-composer-xe-2013-sp1-update-1-error-libraries-could-not-be-loaded-libmkl-intel).

Comment: Are the 150 `a class marked shared may not have a base class whose size is not a multipe of 8` and the `a class with multiple base classes may not be marked shared` warnings normal?

Comment: This does not work, it does, however, compile.

Comment: Do you compile using the Makefile? E.g. something like `nmake offload=mic`? Please pay attention to the following command line keys used to build it for offload: `/D__TBB_MIC_OFFLOAD /Qdiag-disable:3335,3440,3441`.

Comment: Let me clarify:I have looked at the example code, and as far as I am aware am now doing the same thing in my MSVS project, and it does not work. What does the makefile specifically do that is relevant to the offload mechanism? is there more to be done than just adding /Qtbb to the compiler?

Comment: So, does the example work? Probably you missed something? If your program compiles but does not work (how?), it's probably not the build options, but the code itself. E.g. pay attention how parallel_for's body functor is declared: `class __declspec(target(mic)) SubStringFinder;` and I'd put braces around parallel_for in order to clearly denote offload region. If it does not help but the example works, try modify it gradually to your code to see what breaks it

Comment: When the code compiled but did not work, the problem was that it did not build the offload code properly, which leads me to believe that the problem is with the build options notably, upon execution the following printout occured `On the sink, dlopen() returned NULL. 
The result of dlerror() is "/var/volatile/tmp/coi_procs/1/6444/load_lib/MY_PROJECT.out: undefined symbol: _ZTVN3tbb4taskE"` I will continue to work with the demo project to see if that will work.

Comment: I see, it's a runtime problem. Your application on the device cannot resolve TBB symbols. try setting MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (which is set for Intel Compiler environment) like here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/window-phi-composer-xe-2013-sp1-update-1-error-libraries-could-not-be-loaded-libmkl-intel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56000/discussion-between-nanos-and-anton).